# PHP Escaping angle brackets for <!--HTML-->?

Tags: escaping, angle, brackets

Having a lot of trouble escaping angle brackets..

```
$embeds = preg_replace(<!--nextpage-->, '', $embeds, 1);
```

Did find that strip_tags() is suppose to do the trick, but must have messed up somewhere.

What would be the best way to remove the < !--nextpage-->?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to strip or to escape angel brackets?

Stripping works with [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) if the HTML is valid. Example: `$embeds = strip_tags($embeds);`

Escaping can be done using [`html_special_chars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Example: `$embeds = htmlspecialchars($embeds, ENT_NOQUOTES);`

You can try the following as well:

```
preg_replace('/<!--.+-->/U', '', $embeds)
```

Comment: Thanks, found that htmlspecialchars() removes everything but the < >, so basically nothing..

The strip_tags() on the other hand strips everything!

..Might there be another way to do this?

Comment: I do not know what you intend to do… htmlspecialchars() _escapes_ the angel brackets, so it does something.

Comment: To remove the first < !--nextpage--> from the $embeds string. If possible.